# getting error while executing my pl/sql code

Tags: plsql, cursor, syntax-error, case

This is my pl/sql block

```
declare 
b_emp_no employees.emp_no%type;
cursor c_employees is 
select emp_no from employees;
begin
open c_employees;
loop
fetch c_employees  into b_emp_no;
exit when c_employees%notfound;
end loop;
case b_emp_no
when b_emp_no=1 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 1');
when b_emp_no=2 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 2');
when b_emp_no=3then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 3');
when b_emp_no=4 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 4');
when b_emp_no=5 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 5');
when b_emp_no=6 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 6');
when b_emp_no=7 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 7');
when b_emp_no=8 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 8');
when b_emp_no=9 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 9');
when b_emp_no=10 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 10');
when b_emp_no=11 then
dbms_output.put_line('employee number is 11');
else 
dbms_output.put_line('employees numbers:'||b_emp_no);
close c_employees;
end;
```

While executing a above pl/sql block.getting error is

```
ORA-06550: line 37, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   case
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I didn't get  where it  showing this error.please rectify my error.i'm failed in rectifying this erro

Answer (score 1):

No "END CASE" in the code, as required by the syntax.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/case_statement.htm